# listing network shares with python

Tags: python, networking, drive

if I explicitly attempt to list the contents of a shared directory on a remote host using python on a windows machine, the operation succeeds, for example, the following snippet works fine:

```
os.listdir("\\\\remotehost\\share")
```

However, if I attempt to list the network drives/directories available on the remote host, python fails, an example of which is shown in the following code snippet:

```
os.listdir("\\\\remotehost")
```

Is anyone aware of why this doesn't work?, any help/workaround is appreciated.

Comment: Does the user have permission to list shares? Or just have permission to list directories in \\remotehost\share?

Comment: yes, the user has sufficient permissions to the shares, even if I set the remote host to my local machine, I still observe the same behaviour

Comment: Just a little tip:

When dealing with huge backslash trails like that, it's generally easier to input the string as a raw string, like this: r'\\remotehost\share' vs '\\\\remotehost\\share'.  That saves me headaches regularly.

Answer (score 5):

May be [pysmb](http://miketeo.net/wp/index.php/projects/pysmb) can help

Answer (score 3):

For anyone still wondering how to list network shares at the top level on windows, you can use the win32net module:

```
import win32net
shares, _, _ = win32net.NetShareEnum('remotehost',0)
```

The integer controls the type of information returned but if you just want a list of the shares then 0 will do.

This works where os.listdir('\\remotehost') fails as '\\remotehost' isn't a real folder although windows can display it like one.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure the OP has forgotten about this question by now, but here's (maybe) an explanation:

http://www.python.org/doc/faq/windows/#why-does-os-path-isdir-fail-on-nt-shared-directories

In case anybody else happens along this problem, like I did.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following script will help you. See http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/ScriptCenter/en-us/7338e3bd-1f88-4da9-a585-17877fa37e3b

Answer (score -1):

Sorry. I'm not able to try this as I'm not in a PC.
Have you tried:

```
os.listdir("\\\\remotehost\\")
```