# Network Shares listing

Tags: python, windows, ironpython, lan, smb

I am in a process to write a lan scan application in python or ironpython . But, it is turning out to be not that easy due to lack of good libraries !! (yes, even i am surprised!! maybe i did'nt search well enough).

[THIS](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/networkshares.aspx) is one library in c# and seems very easy to use for the purpose.

And, as per [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459590/listing-network-shares-with-python)  it seems pysmb is the best tool available till now, but it didnt work for me as it was asking for authentication to connect to remote machine even if authentication is not required for accessing those shares.

Does any body have a better solution or recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

Look into WMI.  Here is a ref to Python library that lets you access WMI queries http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/index.html  here is a link to how to use WMI to get a list of network shares http://vbscriptblog.com/vbscript/wmi/shares/wmi-vbscript-to-show-the-network-shares-of-a-computer/  the last script is in VBS.  So if you combine these two together you will get your desired result.

Comment: I have checked this. With wmi I can view my shares, but when i use it for someone else's it gives access denied even though no authentication is required. Have you faced it ?

Comment: I have come across this statement "the firewall of the remote machine needs the following ports opened for WMI: TCP 135, TCP 4168 and UDP 9256". Certainly cant have this constraint :(

Comment: Without TCP 135, it won't work. What the other two are, I don't know.

Comment: I am always getting "x_access_denied: <x_wmi: Unexpected COM Error (-2147024891, 'Access is denied.'," error with WMI when used for other machines. It might be an user rights issue, but it doesnt suite my application.