# File permissions with python

Tags: python, permissions, operating-system

I have an xml file on a windows network drive that I am trying to read and write to. I have full permission to edit the file normally (in gedit or anything), but when I attempt to parse the xml file in python, I get a permissions error. Any ideas?

Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
file = "/directory/to/xml/file"
nfo = ET.parse(file)
```

I then read info from the file and write to the file. It hangs up when trying to write to the file (even though when I use gedit, I can write to the file fine)

the error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parser.py", line 277, in <module>
    nfo.write(file)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 803, in write
    file = open(file_or_filename, "wb")
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/directory/to/xml/file'
```

Comment: Can you post some code and perhaps the actual error message?

Comment: Sorry about that. I posted a shortened version with the error included

Comment: Have you tried eliminating whatever method you are using to mount the Windows network drive? For example, copy the file to your desktop and try to run the Python script against that location.

Comment: Maybe pysmb will help. http://miketeo.net/wp/index.php/projects/pysmb (from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459590/listing-network-shares-with-python)

Answer (score 1):

1. are you sure that gedit does not ignore lack of write permission if you're the file owner? vim can do that, and maybe gedit too? I'd start with simple `ls -l /directory/to/xml/file`.
2. you can always do `strace -f /path/to/your_program.py`, that should give you more info on what is actually being attempted by python runtime.