# Retrieving contents from a directory on a network drive (windows)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm have an issue about displaying the files from a network drive on Windows.

```
path = "\\\\nexus\\File Server\\Technical\\MyDrive\\Software\\Releases\\%s\\%s\\" %(release, module)
```

where `\\nexus\` is a network drive.

My main issue is given that a user enters correct variables, i'm unable to show the contents of the directory requested (the contents of 'module').

### Things I've tried

1. `os.listdir(path)`
   The issue with the line above is that it returns a windows error [123] which is, a can not find directory error. This is because listdir() seems to double all the back slashes
   resulting in :

   ```
    "\\\\\\\\nexus\\File Server\\\\Technical\\\\MyDrive\\\\Software\\\\Releases\\\\release\\\\module\\\\"
   ```
2. `print(glob.glob(path))`
   I didn't really know exactly how it  works :P but it seems just to display the directory supplied and not the contents of the ending directory

   ```
     \\nexus\File Server\Technical\MyDrive\Software\Releases\release\module\"
   ```

I've seen an `os.walk` however im not sure how its works, in that how does it defines what is the base directory /directories and what is the rest of the path

Extra notes: The contents of 'module' will always be a zip file, also the directory will generally contain at maximum five zip files.

Comment: you should remove all the double slashes you have. use a raw string by putting `r` in front of it. so it should look like this: `r'\\nexus\File Server\Technical\MyDrive\Software\Releases\release\module\'` thats the first thing. try that. secondly, on windows, you can also use forward slashes, like this: `r'\\nexus/File Server/Technical/MyDrive/Software/Releases/release/module/'` but you still need the double backslash for a network resource.

Comment: Try this out: path = "//nexus/File Server/Technical/MyDrive/Software/Releases/%s/%s/" %(release, module)

Comment: @InbarRose: Not with the trailing backslash, that won't work.. `module\'` escapes that closing `'`, even in raw string literals.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes, thanks, its early in the morning and i still haven't finished my coffee :)

Comment: Can you simply map `\\nexus` to `Z:`? Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459590/listing-network-shares-with-python

Comment: Or could you include your domain? I.e. try `os.listdir('\\\\nexus.mydomain.com\File Server')`

Comment: @ Inbar.R yeah actuallt providing the string as a raw one was one of the first things i did initially when creating this, howver i forgot to menton it above, all in all the it still results in doubling all the slashes if they are back slashes

Comment: @ Alex changing from \\nexus\ --> Z: still resulted in the same error,

Comment: @AlexL also thanks for revising my original question, also providing the full domain still returns the same "system can not find path"

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just tested on my XP PC, Python 2.7, SMB share `\\myshare`

```
os.listdir('\\\\myshare') # Fails with "WindowsError: [Error 53] The network path was not found"

os.listdir('\\\\myshare/folder') # Succeeds
```

I think some of the confusion could be caused by WindowsError showing the `repr()` of the path, rather than the actual path -

```
>>> repr(path)
"'\\\\myshare'"
>>> str(path)
'\\myshare'
```

If this is a Python 3 & unicode problem, I suggest trying to fix the string first:

```
path = "\\\\myshare\folder"
path = bytes(path, "utf-8").decode("unicode_escape")
print os.listdir(path)
```

(unfortunately I can't test this since I don't have Python 3 installed, but please let me know if it works and I'll edit my answer)

Comment: Intersting you should mention a unicode problem, IDLE (temporary python IDE complains unless i save the script encoded as utf-8.

Comment: Also since im not at work tomorrow i cant really test any new solutions or ideas until Monday, i can vpn into our network however im not sure how python will handle it
Thanks for all replies,

Comment: @JohnSmith No worries, let me know how you go when you get a chance. I suggest trying to make sure that Python thinks `\\nexus\File Server\Technical` exists first, then you can worry about replacing strings :). (`isdir()` or `exists()` should help)

Comment: What happen if the shared folder has credentials? I have the username and password. Where should I put these parameters?

Comment: @gs_developer_user3605534 - does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28865050/python-can-i-suppy-username-and-password-to-os-listdir help?

Comment: This is not working for python3, windows shared folder., can you please tell me revised solution?

Comment: I was literally half day looking for this. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

This one worked for me:

```
os.listdir('\\\\server\folder\subfolder\etc')
```

(with Python 2.7 32b on Win7 64b)

Comment: as it seems, also `'\\\\server/folder'` and `'//server/folder'` works

Answer (score 0):

The workaround for this issue is following:

```
os.listdir('\\networkshares\\folder1\\folder2\\folder3')
```

It means that you have to use double slashes instead of single one.