# python's os.listdir() of network share fails on 64bit machines

Tags: python, windows, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

here is snippet:

```
p = r"\\server\folder1\folder2"
print p
files = os.listdir(p)
print "found files: ", len(files)
```

The output on 32bit machine:

```
\\server\folder1\folder2
found files: 9818
```

The output on 64bit machine:

```
\\server\folder1\folder2
found files: 9818
```

**or**

```
\\server\folder1\folder2
<type 'exceptions.WindowsError'> [Error 24] The program issued a command but the command length is incorrect: '\\\\server\\folder1\\folder2/*.*'
```

I have tried
- Python 2.5, 2.7, 32bit and also 64bit (on 64bit machines).
- machines are 32bit and 64bit.

The network share is accessible and I have read/write rights.

Any one knows why the error is raised **only on 64bit machine**???

thx,
r

Comment: Perhaps the system call status code will be more helpful. Install the [Debugging Tools for Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff551063). Set a system environment variable for debug symbols: `_NT_SYMBOL_PATH=symsrv*symsrv.dll*C:\Symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols`. Run your script with `-i`. Attach to python.exe in the debugger. Set a breakpoint on the system call: `bp ntdll!NtQueryDirectoryFile; g`. In Python, call `os.listdir(p)`. In the debugger enter `pt; r rax` to step to the function return and print the status code. Enter `g` to continue.

Comment: thx! I will give a try.

Comment: You could also try the following without having to use a debugger. Initial setup: `import ctypes;` `ntdll = ctypes.WinDLL('ntdll');` `ntdll.RtlGetLastNtStatus.restype = ctypes.c_uint`. Then in an `except` block handling the exception you can set `ntstatus = hex(ntdll.RtlGetLastNtStatus())`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it is working on 64 bit machine

```
import os
p = r"server/folder1"
print p
files = os.listdir(p)
print "found files: ", len(files)
```

Comment: Thank you! but still same error - WindowsError: [Error 24] The program issued a command but the command length is incorrect: '//server/folder1/folder2/*.*'

Comment: I have tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354113/retrieving-contents-from-a-directory-on-a-network-drive-windows Now I get the error sometimes... I use \\server/folder1/folder2 - could that latency problems? connection issues...

Comment: @compling the path in your example, `r"\\server\folder1\folder2"`, is correct and the canonical form of a UNC path.

Comment: what path are you providing as input?

Comment: @himanshudua I have tried already combinations r"\\server\folder1\folder2", r"\\server/folder1/folder2", "\\\\server\\folder1\\folder2", "\\\\server/folder1/folder2", and so on... Also tried on different computers (win64), the error is mystic - if once it works, next time it does not...

Comment: @compling Check out the new code its working on my 64 bit windows 8 machine

Comment: @compling try r"server/folder1"

Comment: @himanshudua THX! indeed I overlooked missing slashes. So now tried r"server/folder1/folder2" and r"/server/folder1/folder2" - both no luck -> Error 3: system can not find path