# How to get a list of directories within root level of a network

Tags: python

How can I list the directories on a network other than using `os.listdir()`

This prompts me error

```
import os

path = r"\\123.12.12.123"
print(os.listdir(path))
```

`FileNotFoundError: [WinError 67] The network name cannot be found: '\\\\123.12.12.123'`

This is fine but **NOT** what I want

```
import os

path = r"\\123.12.12.123\abc"
print(os.listdir(path))
```

Tried all these and got the same error code.

```
path = "\\\\123.12.12.123"
path = "\\\\123.12.12.123\\"
path = "//123.12.12.123"
```

UPDATE:

> it's a server address but not a valid UNC path. \123.12.12.123\abc is the actual root of a shared drive.

`os.listdir()` will not do the job, we will need to use some other alternative to list the share drives as mentioned in answer section.

Comment: @CheangWaiBin there is no such path as `\\123.12.12.123`, it's a server address but not a valid UNC path. `\\123.12.12.123\abc` is the actual root of a shared drive.

Comment: I think its duplicate. Please see this question in SO [list network win directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354113/retrieving-contents-from-a-directory-on-a-network-drive-windows/14354523])

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieving contents from a directory on a network drive (windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354113/retrieving-contents-from-a-directory-on-a-network-drive-windows)

Comment: @Masklinn So it's impossible to get the directories of that server address am i right?

Comment: @Adam No, the answer over there is getting the directories of the server address + 1 level, I tried the solution it doesnt work because i'm trying to get the directories of the server address, it seems like ```os.listdir``` is not able to get what I want, that's why i'm trying to look for other alternative.

Comment: @CheangWaiBin not via `os.listdir`, [you need to use `net view` for this information](https://serverfault.com/questions/17710/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-shared-directories-on-local-windows-server). It is also available in the win32 API through [NetShareEnum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/lmshare/nf-lmshare-netshareenum?redirectedfrom=MSDN), which [is mapped in PyWin32](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32net__NetShareEnum_meth.html), so that's also an option though a more constraining one (as you need to install pywin32).

Comment: @Masklinn, the `pywin32` solution sounds interesting too! Could you post this as an answer, possibly with a short example or a good reference to it? (The Python library itself does not seem to be that well documented...)

Comment: @Masklinn, the API reference you linked seems to be helpful after all. It was rather trivial to get it working. I can post a working example, but don't want to "steal your credits" ;-) But if you don't want to post it as answer, I will.

Comment: @wovano feel free to post a real answer, I don't really dev *on* windows, I'm just dimly aware of pywin32 (and path UNC issues as they come up in cross-platform code), so I'm not going to write a "proper" answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows you could use the Win32 API function [NetShareEnum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/lmshare/nf-lmshare-netshareenum).

The Python module [pywin32](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/) provides access to much of the Win32 API, including the NetShareEnum function, which is availabe as [`win32net.NetShareEnum`](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32net__NetShareEnum_meth.html). The easiest way to find your shares would be using the Python command `[x[0] for x in win32net.NetShareEnum('123.12.12.123')]`.

To demonstrate how this could be used, the following example prints all directories for all shares found on localhost:

```py
import os
import win32net

def get_shares(server):
    return [x[0] for x in win32net.NetShareEnum(server)]

def print_shares_and_directories(server):
    shares = get_shares(server)
    for share in shares:
        print('SHARE: %s' % share)
        path = '\\\\%s\\%s' % (server, share)
        try:
            files = os.listdir(path)
        except OSError:
            print('    (Directory listing failed)')
        else:
            for file in files:
                if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path, file)):
                    print('    %s' % file)

print_shares_and_directories('localhost')
```

Credits to [Masklinn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8182118/masklinn), who provided the relevant information in a comment.

Answer (score 2):

`net view` will get the directory of the server address

net view by default returns a table-like output, using `-match` and `-replace` to get rid of unneeded info

the output will be in byte form, `decode('utf-8')` will convert the byte to string

```
import subprocess

path = r"\\123.12.12.123"
directory = subprocess.Popen(['powershell', r"(net view {}) -match '\sDisk\s' -replace '\s+Disk.*'".format(path)], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
result = [item.decode('utf-8') for item in directory.communicate()[0].splitlines()]
```

Answer (score -3):

How about this one?

```
path = "\\123.12.12.123"
print(path)
# '\\123.12.12.123'
```

Please try the code above.

Comment: Nope, didn't work obviously ```FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: '\\123.12.12.123'```

Comment: You want to access files via local internet, right?

Comment: No, I'm trying to get the directories name on the network